# add class to parent if child exists

Tags: jquery, css, codeigniter

hi im using codeigniter to generate a form the form error only shows if there is an error for that field i to use twitter-bootstrap for styling so i need a way to add a class of error to both the div (with class="clear fix") and the input if (span class="help-inline") exists as child.

would prefer not to use query so it will degrade properly but any option would be good

any help would be great. hope that makes sense. code is below thanks

```
    <?php echo form_open('login'); ?>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="clearfix">
         <?php echo form_label('Email Address: ', 'email_address');?>
         <div class="input"><?php echo form_input('email_address', set_value('email_address'), 'id="email_address" class="xlarge" autofocus ');?>
         <?php echo form_error('email_address', '<span class="help-inline">', '</span>'); ?>
         </div>
    </div><!-- /clearfix -->
    <div class="clearfix">
         <?php echo form_label('Password: ', 'password');?>
         <div class="input"><?php echo form_input('password', '', 'id="password" class="xlarge"');?>
         <?php echo form_error('password', '<span class="help-inline">', '</span>'); ?>
         </div>
    </div><!-- /clearfix -->
    <div class="actions">
       <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Login', 'class="btn primary"'); ?>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

rendered html(if error is triggered)

```
<form action="http://unetics.site/index.php/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="c0856f469b1f498480881a8512042ccf" />
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <label for="email_address">Email Address: </label>
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" name="email_address" value="" id="email_address" class="xlarge" autofocus  />             
                <span class="help-inline">The Email Address field is required.</span>                   </div>
        </div><!-- /clearfix -->
        <div class="clearfix">
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <div class="input"><input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password" class="xlarge" />
                <span class="help-inline">The Password field is required.</span>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /clearfix -->
        <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn primary" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: also don't know if this changes anything but I'm using less to generate my css

Comment: Show the rendered html; the php (server-side) is entirely irrelevant to JavaScript (client-side).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using:

```
$('.help-inline').closest('.clear-fix').addClass('error').end().prev('input').addClass('error');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eLCxb/).

[JS Fiddle demo, with your rendered html](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eLCxb/2/) (note that I've changed the jQuery `closest()` to: `closest('.clearfix')`).

Or:

```
$('.clear-fix').each(
    function(){
        if ($(this).has('.help-inline')){
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).find('input').addClass('error');
        }
     });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eLCxb/1/).

[JS Fiddle demo, with your rendered html](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eLCxb/4/) (note that I've changed the jQuery selector to: `$('.clearfix')`).

Comment: thanks thats great makes perfect sense and works in JS Fiddle but will not work on my site for some reason

Comment: Check the edits. I had used `clear-fix` instead of `.clearfix` in the original demonstrations. I've since changed that in the newly-amended demos (as noted besides those new links).

Comment: thought it was working but now it highlights all regardless of child (does the same in your js fiddle

Comment: In your posted HTML both clearfix divs contain a `help-inline` span. So it's doing as you asked, isn't it?